# Java AWT/Swing "contains" and "intersects" methods not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm attempting to teach myself some Java AWT and simple graphics but have had difficulty with using the contains and intersects method.

The problem is that it seems to detect the collision several pixels up from where the mouse is clicked and the actual shape.

**GameDemo.java**

```
package uk.co.mhayward.games.sandbox;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameDemo extends JFrame {

    GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameDemo();
    }

    public GameDemo() {
        super("click me");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(gamePanel);
        this.setSize(200, 200);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getPoint().toString());
                if (gamePanel.shape.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    System.out.println("IN");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("out");
                }
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
    }

    public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

        Shape shape = new RegularPolygon(100, 100, 100, 6, 0);

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
            g2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fill(shape);
            g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.draw(shape);
        }
    }

    public static class RegularPolygon extends Polygon {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8828151557263250246L;

        /**
         * @param x
         * @param y
         * @param r
         * @param vertexCount
         */
        public RegularPolygon(int x, int y, int r, int vertexCount) {
            this(x, y, r, vertexCount, 0);
        }

        /**
         * @param x
         * @param y
         * @param r
         * @param vertexCount
         * @param startAngle
         *            360deg = PI
         */
        public RegularPolygon(int x, int y, int r, int vertexCount, double startAngle) {
            super(getXCoordinates(x, y, r, vertexCount, startAngle),
                    getYCoordinates(x, y, r, vertexCount, startAngle),
                    vertexCount);
        }

        protected static int[] getXCoordinates(int x, int y, int r, int vertexCount, double startAngle) {
            int res[] = new int[vertexCount];
            double addAngle = 2 * Math.PI / vertexCount;
            double angle = startAngle;
            for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
                res[i] = (int) Math.round(r * Math.cos(angle)) + x;
                angle += addAngle;
            }
            return res;
        }

        protected static int[] getYCoordinates(int x, int y, int r, int vertexCount, double startAngle) {
            int res[] = new int[vertexCount];
            double addAngle = 2 * Math.PI / vertexCount;
            double angle = startAngle;
            for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
                res[i] = (int) Math.round(r * Math.sin(angle)) + y;
                angle += addAngle;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITS**

*04/Jan/12* - changed Override paint(g) to paintComponent(g) - still doesn't detect collision properly.
*05/Jan/12* - created a SSCCE to more easily demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen on the panel, rather than the JFrame. The offset you are seeing is from the titlebar.

Answer (score 5):

For reference, this [short](http://sscce.org/) [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon) examines a transformed [`Polygon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) using the [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#contains%28double,%20double%29) method. The result seems correct to the nearest pixel. You might compare it to your result.

Answer (score 2):

you have override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` for Swing JComponents instead of method valid for AWT `paint(Graphics g)`, more in tutorials [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)  and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: doesn't seem to have worked, it still has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you have override paintComponent(Graphics g) for Swing JComponents instead of method valid for AWT paint(Graphics g)

Comment: doesn't seem to have worked, it still has the same behaviour.